# What's the meaning of か and も in this sentence?

Tags: words

This is a sentence I'm struggling to fully understand:

> 高校生に**も**なった少女たちに揃い制服を着せ、ボタンをきちんととめている**か**、指定通りのネクタイを締めている**か**、いちいち干渉し、その上でさらに靴からマフラーからヘアアクセサリーにいたるまで、細かく取決めや 禁止事項を設けることへの、疑問がないと言えば嘘になる

I think it's about things high school students have to do as regulation, and it's saying that would be a lie to say there were no issue about what regulations permit or ban; but I'm not sure about the meaning of `も` in `にもなった`, and of `か` in `ボタンをきちんととめているか、指定通りのネクタイを締めているか` (something like `とか`, meaning "or/something like", maybe?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, も emphasizes the meaning of the sentence. As seen in definition 1 in this [dictionary](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%AB%E3%82%82-592921), に and も can work together to put stress on the word 高校生.

Let's see the slight difference between に and にも using your example.

- 「高校生 **に** なった少女たちに揃い制服を着せ...」 tells us just the fact that the school (or somebody) makes their female students wear a uniform.
- 「高校生 **にも** なった少女たちに揃い制服を着せ...」 means that even the high school girls have to wear a uniform. Sometimes, the sentence implicitly includes the writer's opinion such as "high school girls are matured enough, but they have to wear a uniform (like children)."

In this context, か expresses doubt rather than "or/something like", and it can be replaced by [かどうか](https://j-nihongo.com/kadouka/).

「ボタンをきちんととめている**か**、指定通りのネクタイを締めている**か**、いちいち干渉し」means that people interfere with how the girls wear their uniform, for example, **whether** they properly button up their shirt, or **whether** they tie an approved tie.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure of the full translation; it's something like `Once high school students, girls wear matching uniforms, and people interfer with on whether they properly button up their shirt, or whether they tie an approved tie, from top to shoes, scarf and hair accessories, and it would be a lie to say there weren't issues with regarding each small agreed and banned item`?

Comment: ^ @Mauro, Hee.. Where did you get that translation?

Comment: It's my best guess using jackie's answer, but I'm not really sure about it, it's a sentence I'm struggling to fully understand.